# Jest hangs when Svelte configuration includes svelte-preprocess

Tags: jestjs, svelte

The Snowpack Svelte template includes a Jest setup which works well for Svelte apps and works out of the box. However, once `svelte-preprocess` is added, **Jest hangs indefinitely**.

This can easily be seen using `https://github.com/agneym/svelte-tailwind-snowpack`, which can be setup with:

`npx create-snowpack-app dir-name --template svelte-tailwind-snowpack`

**svelte.config.js** looks like this, although even if the pre-processor doesn't include Tailwind it still hangs:

```
const sveltePreprocess = require("svelte-preprocess");

const preprocess = sveltePreprocess({
  postcss: {
    plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")],
  },
});

module.exports = {
  preprocess,
};
```

**jest.config.js**

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

// Use this instead of `paths.testsSetup` to avoid putting
// an absolute filename into configuration after ejecting.
// const setupTestsFile = fs.existsSync(paths.testsSetup)
//   ? `<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js`
//   : undefined;
const setupTestsFile = true;

module.exports = function () {

  const userSvelteConfig = getUserSvelteConfig();

  return {
    testMatch: [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    ],
    transform: {
      "^.+\\.svelte$": [
        "jest-transform-svelte",
        { preprocess: userSvelteConfig.preprocess },
      ],
      "^.+\\.(js|ts)$": path.resolve(__dirname, "jest/babelTransform.js"),
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "ts", "svelte"],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules"],
    transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules"],
    bail: false,
    verbose: true,
    setupFilesAfterEnv: setupTestsFile ? ["<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"] : [],
  };
};

function getUserSvelteConfig() {
  const userSvelteConfigLoc = path.join(process.cwd(), "svelte.config.js");
  if (fs.existsSync(userSvelteConfigLoc)) {
    return require(userSvelteConfigLoc);
  }

  return {};
}
```

Comment: We had a similar issue and figured out it was linked to `deasync` hanging on some node version. We have rewritten `jest-transform-svelte` for our own needs using the same way than svelte-jester, you can have a look at https://github.com/oat-sa/jest-transform-svelte

Answer (score 0):

Have to eject the default Snowpack configuration file and use `svelte-jester` instead of the config they were using. The config below works:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

// Use this instead of `paths.testsSetup` to avoid putting
// an absolute filename into configuration after ejecting.
// const setupTestsFile = fs.existsSync(paths.testsSetup)
//   ? `<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js`
//   : undefined;
const setupTestsFile = true;

module.exports = function () {

  const userSvelteConfig = getUserSvelteConfig();

  return {
    rootDir: "./",
    testMatch: [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    ],
    transform: {
      "^.+\\.svelte$": [
        "svelte-jester",
        { "preprocess": true },
      ],
      "^.+\\.(js|ts)$": "babel-jest",
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "ts", "svelte"],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules"],
    transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules"],
    bail: false,
    verbose: true,
    setupFilesAfterEnv: setupTestsFile ? ["<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"] : [],
  };
};

function getUserSvelteConfig() {
  const userSvelteConfigLoc = path.join(process.cwd(), "svelte.config.js");
  if (fs.existsSync(userSvelteConfigLoc)) {
    return require(userSvelteConfigLoc);
  }

  return {};
}
```